# Print multiple images using Process.StartInfo.Verb=“print” command

Tags: c#, windows, image, printing

I am using this code for print with windows print pictures...

```
string fileName = @"C:\Images\12.jpg";
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
p.Start();
```

I want to open multiple images from directory into this, how can i do it?

I tried this code, but does not work:

```
var p = new Process();
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"Directory address");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName += file.FullName.ToList();
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
    p.Start();
}
```

Comment: file.FullName.ToList() is going to return a list of all the characters within a full name, is that really what you want?

Comment: Hope this help http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/ and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/3ef19bea-66a5-4dc5-bdbe-b59b86b38e3d/print-pdf-files-in-c-code-with-process

Comment: i just want to add all pictures into that dialog...

Comment: the problem of my code is this line..." p.StartInfo.FileName += file.FullName.ToList(); " i do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

From your code example, it appears you want to simply invoke separate "print" verb commands for each file. If so, then you should be able to accomplish that by simply assigning the file name in your loop, instead of enumerating the characters of the file name and appending that to the `FileName` property:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"Directory address");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg");
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.Verb = "Print";
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    psi.FileName = file.FullName;
    Process.Start(psi);
}
```

Note that you can't reuse a single `Process` object for this purpose. Once a given `Process` object has been started, it can't be started again. But you *can* reuse a `ProcessStartInfo` object, starting a new process with each iteration of the loop.

**EDIT:**

From your comment:

> I do not want to simply invoke separate "print" verb commands for each file...I want to add all files in one "print" verb command

This is not possible using the `Process` class. By definition, the DDE "print" verb (i.e. "command") handles only a single document. If you are willing to do a lot of extra work, you can write your own DDE client that attempts to use DDEEXEC to iteratively interact with a DDE server that knows how to print your image files. But a) this *is* a lot more work, and b) it still will only work if you happen to have a program installed that handles printing of image files via DDEEXEC (the Windows built-in support for printing images does not).

I recommend you stick with the above.

(And for future reference, if you only want to call `Process.Start()` once, putting it inside a loop is definitely not the way to go. Your question would have been more clear if your example code bore any resemblance at all to what you were actually trying to do. :) )

Comment: no, I do not want to simply invoke separate "print" verb commands for each file...I want to add all files in one "print" verb command...